# Why is $X=\{1,a,b\}$,with cayley table $aa=a,bb=b,ab=1,1a=a1=a,1b=1b$ not a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For exercise, I was trying to construct a group of order $3$:

ofc, I know that $\{1,a,b\}$ with $ab=ba=1,aa=b$, it's cyclic group of order $Z3$.

However, what if I have something like:

$\{1,a,b\},$ with $aa=a,bb=b,ab=1$, and sure $a1=1a=a,b1=1b=b$?

There is something about the identity elements.

according to the definition:

$1$ is still identity, $a,b$ are inverses of each other, and one can check $aaa...bbb...aaa = aaa...(aaa...bbb)..bbb=1$, is always associative. the funny thing is , $a$ and $b$ both have no finite order,since $a^n = a$ and $b^n=b$ for all number $n$ (multiply by itself $n$ times), hence this is not the same as $Z3$

Why is this not a group? So, if this is not a group, then is it the case that we have to put

"each elements has unique identity element $1$" as part of the requirement?

But everywhere I check, they say unique identity is a consequence of the definition.

Or is it something about definition of binary operation that not allowing things like $aa=a$?

What am I missing ? Thanks all

Comment: I have this question because "all group of order 3 is isomorphic to Z3", but the one i created is not.....i think there is something about the group definition i am not getting, but this construction do satisfy:closure,inverse, associative.and "there is an identity to all element in group,(namely 1)"

Comment: If you write out the group operation table, it must be a Latin square:  each row and column must have one of each element in it.  Your row $a$ will have two $a$s and a $1$, so no $b$.

Comment: It's not associative $(aa)b = ab = 1$ but $a(ab) = a1 = a$.  (Also you forgot to mention what $ba$ is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $aa=a,$ then multiplying sides by $a^{-1}$ gives $a=1.$ But your setup of a set of *three* elements $\{1,a,b\}$ would not be right then.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. A good question may I add, will upvote it.,

Answer (score 2):

There is an identity and every element has an inverse, so if it's not a group then the operation must fail to be associative. I don't understand your associativity argument, but 
$$(ab)b = 1b = b$$ $$a(bb) = ab = 1.$$